# How do JMeter load test stream upload

Tags: testing, jmeter, stress-testing, jmeter-plugins

I developed a stream upload with NodeJS. A webform send the files wit Jquery File Upload plugin (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/) and this plugin made the socket with the server.

When i try do the load test on JMeter the only option is send the file via POST method on http request, causing this a normal post upload, but i want try the stream.

At same time i upload via browser to my server to compare.

Result: all users failing (web browser no).

How i can do the JMeter upload via websocket stream to test the server down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery needs a fully running DOM + JavaScript engine and that's just not provided by JMeter.

In order to achieve the goal:

1. Create a selenium webdriver script for the scenario
2. Run it via Jmeter using Webdriver plugin
   http://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/file/JMeterPlugins-WebDriver-1.1.3.zip